# React js: npm ERR! Missing script: "build"

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-build

I created a new app using the react template.
In my github actions, When I first did the npm install, it went well
Later I tried, the npm run build . It failed with   npm ERR! Missing script: "build"
But the build script is present in my package.json file

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Comment: Make sure you are running the command from the folder containing your package.json file also make sure you don't have duplicate `scripts` properties there

Comment: @Hatana yes, I am running in the same folder. And yes there is only one scripts properties. But looks like I am missing something here. I tried difference things like clean cache and all but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Verify `react-scripts` installation: The `react-scripts` package typically provides the build script, which is a development dependency. Confirm that `react-scripts` is correctly listed under `devDependencies` in your `package.json` file. If it's missing, you can install it by running:

```batch
npm install react-scripts --save-dev
```

Comment: it is listed in my dev dependecies  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "jest-editor-support": "^31.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  }

Comment: @Petr the `start` script is working so react-script should be installed